# Issue at opening a video with VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm unable to open some avi files with Videocapture from opencv. In fact, I just have one video which works, but none of my other videos will open.

The code I use:

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.avi')

while True:

 ret, frame = cap.read()

 if ret == True:

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)


  if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

else:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: is there an error? can you you capture the the frame in an array?

Comment: There isn't any error, nothing happen when i run the program.

I added the lines: 

    for i in range (16)
      cap.get()

And it returned me only zeros even for the frames number, the length and the width of the video.